# Tire showing low pressure after few KMs of ride

Tags: tires, temperature, pressure

I am having this question from long back.

I am using N2 for my tyres.

After a few KM (say some 3-4 KMs), measuring the PSI, shows a less pressure.

Whether, due to the increase in the temperature in the tyre, the density or the pressure is decreased?

1. If it is so, will it escape from the tyre, I mean the tyre pressure will be reduced easily??
2. The same thing will happen for the tyre with the normal air
3. Having a tyre with tube when compared to tubeless, will resolve this problem.
   (I am not going to change it from tubeless to tube)..
4. The loss of air is directly proportional to heat of the tyre, or it will lose it molecule after some days/months..

I got hanged up with this questions. Please help me to understand the things better.

**PS:-**
Hi I am measuring the pressure in the hot tire (I mean, I am doing it immediately after the ride in the fuel station). But I have noticed as, Lets take the following case :- 1. Before 1 Month I have checked the PSI for the tyre and it says, some 28 PSI and 17 PSI (for rear and front) and I will fill it up to 35PSI and 25PSI respectively. After some 20-25 days or even a month ride, I have checked that it is saying close to 27-28 for rear and some 15-17 for the front. All I am doing in the hot tyre. This makes me little confused. Why it is showing less PSI in hot tyre.?

Thanks in advance friends...

Comment: When a tire heats up, the pressure normally goes up.  Gasses expand when they get hotter.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Are you measuring the tire pressures under the same conditions? Cold/hot tire?

Comment: They have Nitrogen in the tires, this is supposed to stabilize pressure from hot to cold.....http://www.edmunds.com/car-care/should-you-fill-your-cars-tires-with-nitrogen.html

Comment: @racefever: Hi I am measuring the pressure in the hot tire (I mean i am doing it immediately after the ride in the fuel station). But I have noticed as, Lets take the following case :- 1. Before 1 Month I have checked the PSI for the tyre and it says, some 28 PSI and 17 PSI (for rear and front) and I will fill it up to 35PSI and 25PSI respectively. After some 20-25 days or even a month ride, I have checked that it is saying close to 27-28 for rear and some 15-17 for the front. All I am doing in the hot tyre. This makes me little confused. Why it is showing less PSI in hot tyre.? Thanks.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Yes, what u have commented is my one of the questions. ["If it is so, will it escape from the tyre, I mean the tyre pressure will be reduced easily??"]. Thanks...

Comment: @user3663241, I agree with the answer from DucatiKiller below.  If the pressure ever goes down, air is leaking somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

**I think you have pressure loss on your bead, pressure sensor or Schrader valve**

Regardless of the tire holding N2 or straight atmospheric gasses, all of the same principles apply to pressure loss.  You need to have a good seal on all of the components of the rim.

- Bead of tire on rim
- Seal of any pressure sensors
- Seal of the Schrader valve
- Seal of the valve stem on the Schrader valve

If you have slow leaks in any of these places you can experience pressure reduction over time.

Driving on the tire will only heat it up and heat on any gas causes expansion.  N2 will have a lower expansion rate but expansion nonetheless.  You have a leak somewhere and that's what you need to resolve.

Here is another post related to pressure loss of a tire over time.

- **[Why do tyres go flat after a few weeks of non-usage?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27282/why-do-tyres-go-flat-after-a-few-weeks-of-non-usage/27283#27283)**